# Error while Compiling an app in android rom. (APK empty)

Tags: android, compilation, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I get the following error when trying to build an apk using **mm**.

```
Reading program jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/APPS/HelloWorld_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-junit_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-libart_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/ext_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar]
Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/HelloWorld_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (20 seconds) ####
```

These are the contents of my make file **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := HelloWorld

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

And this is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.helloworld" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorld"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_HELLOWORLD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The app above compiles fine in the android studio. To compile it in the same environment that i'm using to compile the Rom, I had to delete the prebuilt R files. Any suggestions that could help compile this app?

Comment: Hey people! can I get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was wrong, The problem was not the progard.flags file, I was trying to compile an app written in Gradle where as the andriod ROM compile environment supports ANT.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. Add `LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags` to your `Android.mk` and create the flags file.

```
-keep class com.yourpackage.* {
  *;
}
```

Comment: ok adding the flags file definitely got me out of this issue but now there are a few others. Have you been able to compile the app? If yes then can I ask you a few quick questions?